# How yo use AWS Lambda for multiple http requests processing?

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, guzzle

I'm building an uptime monitoring tool.

I have 5 VPS servers that do HTTP requests to many URLs every minute. Now, I've heard that AWS Lambda may reduce my costs and is a good fit for such task. I got no experience with Lambda.

If 1 invocation would be 1 request, then it'd be very expensive to use. I have:
1000 urls * 1 minute * 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours * 1 month * 5 locations = 216 millions of invocations which is much more costly than I have with VPS.

I'm using Laravel + Guzzle for making requests. I have a laravel job which makes the request to one URL.

How can I optimize the process? Should I use Guzzle concurrent requests or is there another common way for solving such task?

Comment: What are your VPS costs per month?

Comment: $ 100-150 I guess

Comment: From the https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/ page, assuming 200M requests of 5 seconds each your costs would be about 10-20X (more with data transfer) from what you're paying now.  Lambda is not a solution for everything.  There is definitely a limit to where it makes sense and you're way past that.

Comment: Yes, but I heard an approach that I can do multithreading or something like that, when 1 lambda call will handle many requests at once. I'm struggling with this right now, cannot write the code part, but maybe there is some simpler solution in this case...?

Comment: I don't know much about your HTTP requests, but you could investigate a single Lambda invocation making many HTTP requests, preferably in parallel. If you were able to do 20 in a single invocation and the slowest result came back within 1 sec then the numbers might be reasonable. You'd have to try this out. Fire up a Lambda invocation, hit 10/20/100 URLs and see what it looks like. Play with the RAM configuration so that you benefit from more network. See if [aws-lambda-power-tuning](https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning) helps. PS don't use PHP ;-)

Comment: @jarmod beat me to it - your biggest challenge would be optimization.  It's going to take a good amount of work to figure out how best to run your queries in parallel.  It doesn't mean it can't be done but depending on the value of your time it may take a long time to pay back.  PHP is not supported out of the box.

Comment: Youre VPS responds to those requests or the VPS is performing the request to other services? In case the second approach applies, and the Lambda in the calls http apis on a schedule, one invokation can for sure perform multiple outbound requests. Maximum time a lambda can run are 15min.